# C++ error in ios_base.h

Tags: c++, gcc

> /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/ios_base.h: In member function ‘std::basic_ios >& std::basic_ios >::operator=(const std::basic_ios >&)’:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/ios_base.h:793: error: ‘std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:47: error: within this context
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd: In member function ‘std::basic_ostream >& std::basic_ostream >::operator=(const std::basic_ostream >&)’:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:56: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios >& std::basic_ios >::operator=(const std::basic_ios >&)’ first required here
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd: In member function ‘std::basic_ofstream >& std::basic_ofstream >::operator=(const std::basic_ofstream >&)’:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:84: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ostream >& std::basic_ostream >::operator=(const std::basic_ostream >&)’ first required here
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/streambuf: In member function ‘std::basic_filebuf >& std::basic_filebuf >::operator=(const std::basic_filebuf >&)’:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/streambuf:778: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]’ is private
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:78: error: within this context
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd: In member function ‘std::basic_ofstream >& std::basic_ofstream >::operator=(const std::basic_ofstream >&)’:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:84: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_filebuf >& std::basic_filebuf >::operator=(const std::basic_filebuf >&)’ first required here

anyone has any idea what is this error about?

**Update**: it comes from the following line:

```
ofstream myOutStream = ofstream(myCurrentLogName.c_str(), ios::app);
```

Comment: Could you post the code that is causing the error. Looks like something to do with access privileges though

Comment: looks like you are using assignment operator on something it doesn't like

Comment: I don't know which part of my code causing this,
all I got is what you see up there.

Comment: @MBZ: Maybe if you post your code, other people would be able to figure out which part is causing it.

Comment: @MBZ:  The error must have been emitted while compiling a certain file.  Can you post that file?

Comment: tnx all, just Updated Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to copy or assign a stream (descendant of `std::istream` or `std::ostream`). Streams, however, cannot be copied or assigned.

***Edit***

Change your code to:

```
std::ofstream myOutStream(myCurrentLogName.c_str(), std::ios::app);
```

Comment: what if I want to reinitialize it later without assigning?

Comment: @MBZ: you can reinitialise it by closing and reopening it.

Comment: @MBZ: Put that code using the stream into a function taking an `std::ostream&`. You can then call that function with different streams.

Answer (score 3):

That is the first line of a two-line error message. The first line gives the location of the private/protected member you're trying to access, and the second line gives the location of the attempt to access it. The full message will look something like

```
header.h:53: error: `thing` is private
source.cpp:99: error: within this context
```

The second line will tell you where to look for the error.

**Update**

That was the answer to the original question. Now we've seen the full error message and the code causing it, sbi has the answer.